# MongoDB and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have a array of mongodb Documents. Now this array may contain duplicate documents. How to insert these document as it is if document is not there in the collection(each document also have _id inside it). I am continously getting a error for duplicate key for duplicate documents. I am not using mongoose instead I am using mongodb native driver.

```
const query = { mappingID: id };
await consumerContainer.findOne(query, async (err, item) => {
  try {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    if (item === null) {
      await consumerContainer.insertOne(result);
    } else {
      console.log('duplicate entries found : ', item._id);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's pretty much self explanatory... If you got a unique key, such as _id, this has to be unique. If you want to still insert the document, you'll have to use a different value for that key.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `await` and using the callback with `findOne`.
Try to change your code like this:

```
const query = { mappingID: id };

try {
  const consumer = await consumerContainer.findOne(query);
  if (!consumer) {
    await consumerContainer.insertOne(result);
  } else {
    console.log('duplicate entries found : ', consumer._id);
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Its still seems to throw the same error, it is as if varriable query is initialized later and actually findOne query runs first

Comment: Can you post the full code?